# Cassandra loads no rows from CSV file

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I want to test the import by only importing three columns, namely `bla, types`and `location`, but 0 rows are imported.

**Sample data:**

```
bla,types,location
1,Warning,90 S 1ST ST
2,Warning,730 W STASSNEY LN

CREATE TABLE data.table (
bla int PRIMARY KEY,
types text,
location text);
```

**Inserting data**

```
copy data.table(bla, types, location) from '/home/data/table.csv' WITH DELIMITER = ',' AND HEADER = true;
```

**Output**

```
Using 1 child processes

Starting copy of data.table with columns [bla, types, location].
Processed: 0 rows; Rate:       0 rows/s; Avg. rate:       0 rows/s
0 rows imported from 1 files in 0.381 seconds (0 skipped).
```

> As you can see it imported 0 rows, but it could locate the csv file as it didn't throw an error.

Comment: Is it possible to put a few lines of the file in this place? The format may be incorrect

Comment: both of them,format and the content of the file

Comment: What does your keyspace definition look like?  Are you setting an appropriate number of replicas to `datacenter1`?

Comment: replication = {'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'datacenter1' : 1};

Comment: can you qoute the location with " "? 
for example : 
1,Warning,"90 S 1ST ST"
2,Warning,"730 W STASSNEY LN"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to fully understand what caused the issue, but it certainly had something to do with the csv formatting. I converted the file into a text file and this seemed to have worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try without whitespaces in the field list:

```
copy data.table (bla,types,location) from '/home/datatable.csv' WITH DELIMITER = ',' AND HEADER = true;
```

Comment: Can you add few lines from the csv you try to import?

Comment: I do not see any comma separated input, but in your copy command you set comma as delimiter. Your input csv should look like: 
bla,types,location
1,Warning,90 S 1ST ST
2,Warning,730 W STASSNEY LN

Comment: Try to run it with --debug to see detailed info.